# How to improve performance for loop function using core data?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, core-data

I have 2 Entities:

```
class Month: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var date: Date        
    @NSManaged var services: Set<Service>

    var duration: Int {
        return services.reduce(0) { $0.duration } + surplusForPreviousMonth
    }
    var surplusForPreviousMonth: Int {
        let date = /*calculate previous month for `date` */        
        guard let PREVIOUSMONTH = Month.mr_findFirstWithPredicate(predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date = %@", date)) else {
            return 0 
        }
        return (PREVIOUSMONTH.duration % 3600)
    }
}

class Service: NSManagedObject {
    var duration: Int
    @NSManaged var month: Month
}
```

But it is time consuming as I have a lot of months and and lot of services in every month. How can I improve it?

It must be good calculated once I change duration for ANY service. Duration for any service changes duration for future months.

How can I speed it up? I use `month.duration` almost everywhere.

Comment: Where is the recursive function?

Comment: Sorry for the question, but where is the recursion?

Comment: oh sorry, I think it is not recursive... but is called for every month unless it doesnt find month

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk show query that stands for  /* find and fetch previous month */ also is it possible to create lazy variables insted?

Comment: lazy variables will not work I think because every time I fetch month again from persistent store. Am I right?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk do you extend Set data type with custom reduce() method ? Is it possible to do profiling of this method ?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Would this work: Calculate the surplusForPreviousMonths in one go: fetch Services using a predicate "month.date < %@".  Calculate the total duration, then %3600.  There should be fewer fetches, particularly since in your current code each Service will be faulted in separately.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk do profiling of method? custom `reduce()`? What do you mean?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk we should measure what is the most expensive operation in the Month class. Reduce method that you are using in the code have different declaration from original.

Comment: @pbasdf you may be right. Should it be faster when I fetch all services with predicate: `month.date < %@`?

Comment: @pbasdf but there is one more thing, if previous month doesnt exist, I should not search for previous one.... Do you have idea how to create predicate to fetch services only to the first month that doesnt exist?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I think it will be faster.  if you enable SQLDebug with your current code, I think you will see multiple fetches occurring: One for each prior month, then one for each service in that month, etc.

Comment: @pbasdf but with your idea it will prevent from multiply fetches, right?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Yes.  But your other point might cause a problem with my proposed approach.  I need to think about that.

Comment: @pbasdf I will think about that also...:)